# Why am I getting an error with plinear algorithm for non-linear regression in R?

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I have a 2 element list with X and Y values which I would like to do non-linear regression on with R.

```
NP  delta_f_norm
3.125E-08   1.305366836
6.25E-08    0
0.000000125 3.048361059
0.00000025  2.709158322
0.0000005   2.919379441
0.000001    42.8860945
0.000002    49.75418233
0.000004    50.89313017
0.000008    50.18050031
0.000016    49.67195257
0.000032    48.89396054
0.000064    48.00787709
0.0000006   16.50229042
0.0000007   8.906829316
0.0000008   14.2697833
2.74E-08    -0.913767771
4.11E-08    -0.942489364
6.17E-08    0.586660918
9.24E-08    -0.080955695
1.387E-07   1.672777115
2.081E-07   0.880006555
3.121E-07   13.23952061
4.682E-07   44.73003305
7.023E-07   57.11640257
1.0535E-06  54.09032726
1.5802E-06  58.71029183
2.3704E-06  56.85467325
3.5556E-06  57.83003606
5.3333E-06  53.71761902
0.000008    53.55511726
```

I import the plain text data, normalize the Y values and change the scale on the x values:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

# load in the data points, make sure the working directory is set correctly
# I have already trimmed data manually, so it is just tab separated, x values in the left
# column, y values in the right, with the first line containing the name of the variable 

bind_curve <- read_tsv("MST_data.txt")
view(bind_curve)

# normalize curve to max
# as fractional occupancy of binding sites

bind_curve$delta_f_norm <- bind_curve$delta_f_norm/max(bind_curve$delta_f_norm)

#change units to nanomolar
bind_curve$NP <- bind_curve$NP*1e06


# due to the way the plinear algorithm works, y values cannot be zero, so we have to change them to very small values

for (i in 1:nrow(bind_curve))
{
  if (bind_curve[i,2] == 0)
  {
    bind_curve[i,2] <- 1e-10
  }
}


# here Ka is the apparent Kd and n is the hill coeficient, the parameters were
# guestimated by looking at the data

view(bind_curve)

hill_model <- nls((delta_f_norm ~ 1/(((Ka/NP)^n)+1)), data = bind_curve, start = list(Ka=700, n=2), algorithm = "plinear")

summary(hill_model)
```

this gives the following error:

```
Error in chol2inv(object$m$Rmat()) : 
  element (2, 2) is zero, so the inverse cannot be computed
```

This makes no sense, as element (2,2) was 0 when it was imported, but I specifically overwrote it with a small non-zero value to allow inversion. Inspection of the data frame before creating the non-linear model even shows the value is not 0, so why is it reporting that it is? Is this an issue where bind_curve exists in 2 different namespaces or something? That's the only possible way I can think that this would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I forgot to convert the units on my initial Ka guess when I changed the units on the NP data (700 vs. 0.7) so obviously my starting values were very far off which must have been what caused it to fail. I don't understand what that has to do with 0 values in the data, but whatever its fixed.

A mod can delete this post. I'm a moron :p